# Why did the wights pile up when they were stabbed by dragonglass?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* S08E03, Before the Battle of Winterfell, it is clear that they tipped the wooden stakes with dragon glass. But why was it that Melisandre still had to cover the trenches in flames?

Also, why did the wights not disintegrate when they got stuck on the dragon glass tipped stakes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wights don't disintegrate when stabbed with Dragonglass or Valyrian steel, they only lose their undeadness and go back to become inanimate corpses.

Only fire can disintegrate them into ash. Also, once they are stabbed with Dragonglass or Valyrian steel, they can't be reanimated by White Walkers.

We saw this clearly in S07E07 at the dragonpit demonstration. When Hound slashes the Wight in half, Jon stabs one part with Dragonglass and it becomes dead again, but doesn't disintegrate. Another part, maybe a hand, he burns with fire.

Comment: But didn't Sam use dragon glass to disintegrate one? That was beyond the wall, and I think that was the first enemy casualty

Comment: @KarlM.Allanic that was a White Walker not a Wight. Wights are undead. White Walkers are living beings created by Night King

Comment: Oooooohhh right, I'm sorry, I always get confused when they get killed. Thanks!